# Close an image with Gimp Script-Fu

Tags: gimp, python-fu

Stoopid question time. How do you close an image in GIMP with Script-Fu?

Sort of the Pythonic version of this: (ignore changes and close)

```
// close the image WITHOUT saving
app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
```

There's nothing in the Python Procedure Browser for "close"

Answer (score 0):

(You title & tag "script-fu", which is Scheme/Lisp, but then mention Python..., so going for Python...)

The theory is that a script shouldn't interfere with the UI, so you can't close an image at random.

If your script loads an image, the image can be shown to the user using a `display=gimp.Display(image)` (this is a `gimp.Display` object). You can also add a display to an already loaded image the same way. Since you created the display, you know it, you own it and so you can close it with `gimp.delete(display)`. When the last display of an image is closed, the image is quitted.

If you don't create the display, you can take advantage of the fact that the display IDs are created in sequence and that this sequence sort of matches the image ids so unless many images have been loaded without a display or many images have go many displays, the display ID and the image ID are close to each other.

And given an integer ID, you can recover the display using the "secret" `gimp._id2display(id)`, so if there is a single image loaded, you can find its Display with something like

```
for displayID in range(1,image.ID+50):
    display=gimp._id2display(displayID)
    if isinstance(display,gimp.Display):
        break
if not display:
    raise Exception('Display not found')            
gimp.delete(display)
```

But this will misbehave if there is more than one image loaded, so beware.

Comment: I've changed the tag - that was my mistake. - I got the fu part right! :)